# What are spaces in the buttons?

Tags: html, css

[buttons' spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnlsT.png)

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="btn-search" type="submit">Google Search</button>
  <button id="btn-lucky" type="submit">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
</div>

.buttons {
  max-width: 290px;
  margin: auto;
}
#btn-search, #btn-lucky {
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  margin:0 4px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
```

Why do these spaces appear?
I use Eric Meyer's reset.

Comment: On second thoughts, and after making a jsfiddle, you are not posting all of your code. You have not posted the css that highlights the text blue, which is the issue.

Comment: @IeuanG These highlights is just selection from my cursor, not css code.

Comment: Your code snippet does not yield the attached image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `space( &nbsp;)`b/w the buttons. Here is the solution.

```css
.buttons {

  max-width: 290px;

  margin: auto;

}

#btn-search,

#btn-lucky {

  height: 34px;

  padding: 0 16px;

  margin: 0px;

  border: 1px solid transparent;

}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="btn-search" type="submit">Google Search</button><button id="btn-lucky" type="submit">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @CosdeRomeos Oh, browser interprets return space how just space between inline-block elements?

Comment: Yes. As in inline-block there are spaces, but those space b/w inline-block are not a bug. Inline-block are treated as combination of word in a sentence. So the spaces are automatically added b/w them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the padding css. your new code would look like

```
<style>
.buttons {
  max-width: 290px;
  margin: auto;
}
#btn-search, #btn-lucky {
  height: 34px;
  margin:0 4px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

</style>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="btn-search" type="submit">Google Search</button>
  <button id="btn-lucky" type="submit">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
</div>
```